# Asymptotes' intersection with curve at infinity

Tags: algebraic-curves

I read in my course book that asymptotes have at least two intersection with algebraic curve at infinity. How can I take this fact in my head in a visualized way? And what does that *at least* means? What are these multiple intersections on infinity ?

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you mean by 'algebraic curve?' Because asymptotes, by definition, do not intersect their curves.

Comment: No. You can't just "assume it is intersecting at infinity". They don't intersect by definition. If you mean that the distance between the asymptote and the curve approaches zero at a point at infinity, then you need to be more precise in your question.

Answer (score 0):

One can say that this is the definition of an asymptote; since an asymptote is a tangent to the curve at a point at infinity, the order of contact between the curve and the asymptote is higher than zero, which can be viewed as a multiple intersection. See the two references [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2922715).

Comment: i wanna know why does the curve and the straight line(asymptote) has atleast two intersection at infinity? See this article on [wikipedia][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote#Algebraic_curves ]; where same thing about intersection is said.

Comment: Have you read the article that I linked to?